# What is the latency of file generation in GCP's CloudLogging feature

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am developing an application that uses GCP's Cloud Logging service (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit). The application analyzes events per each JSON file log. That said, the application promises to do this as soon as possible, but I see that the JSON provided by the Cloud Logging service on GCP only produces JSON once an hour or in some cases, once every few hours.

See screenshot attached as link below (Audit log bucket). In there, we see that the logs are created in a flurry at the 6th minute of the hour (see the Created time column), but then we have to wait a full hour before the next flurry of logs.

[Audit log bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkpEa.png)

What can I do to generate these logs, say, once every 15 minutes?

Comment: Edit your question with details. I see logs with a delay of seconds (less than a minute). To answer your question: You have no control over when logs are generated for managed services. For self-managed services, you can write logs whenever you want and typically five or ten seconds later the log entries will appear.

Comment: Do you want a near real time processing of the log? Create a sink in PubSub instead of in a file, and process the message as they arrived (with a functions or dataflow)

Comment: @JohnHanley, I just added a pic to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs (see under Exported logs availability/Routing frequency).

Basically, once an hour is the best I can expect per service guidelines.